# Do I understand correctly what is .subscribe()? (Angular8)

Tags: angular, typescript

Does subscribe update data when there is a new change??
I saw this code (for angular material table):

```
 this.nameFilter.valueChanges
      .subscribe(
        name => {
          this.filterValues.name = name;
          this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
        }
      )
```

I understand from this code that each time there is a change in `nameFilter` variable, this information is updated in other variables/objects, does it?

Probably, can I explain that it's like a subscription that updates me when there are new changes (so i can use the updated data)?

if you need more about this code, i copied it from here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-column-filter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I so appreciate your answer and the time you spend to clarify the issue for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try your own, then you can understand what is the subscribe mean.

Make this property in your typescript:

```js
valueChanges: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

handleChange(value: string): void {
    this.valueChanges.emit(value);
}
```

Make sure to import EventEmitter from `@angular/core`.

Now, you can try to add input on you html like this code below:

```
<input type="text" (change)="handleChange($event.target.value)" />
```

For the last things, add this subscribe in your `ngOnInit()`:

```js
this.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

So, now from your case, it's mean, when filter variable change, 'material column filter' will emit the value changes to you, so you can set the data source filter.

Yeah, it's mean, it is the rule of the component. But, different component use different rule.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.
Yes subscriptions are used to look at data when it changes. This is mostly restricted to observables. In your example you are looking at an object with the valueChanges attribute which is an observable.
[value changes documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0ukZ.png)

I found this the most helpful in my research to columate what i know. https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3

An observable is like a newsletter service when it receives a new subscription it will send the new news letter to the subscriber as well as all its other subscriptions.
I guess that's why people say you need to unsubscribe all the time.

other references:

https://angular.io/guide/observables

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription

Happy codeing

Answer (score 1):

A subscription (the return type for .subscribe) in rxjs executes code after an asynchronous event finishes.  It is similar to a promise with the difference that it does not necessarily complete after the initial event finishes.

In the example above, an event is triggers with the nameFilter element fires a valueChanges event.  Observables are the events that are listened for and calling .subscribe on the observable makes the observable "hot" meaning the asynchronous code is executed.

Some common observables that can be created are native HTML DOM events (`fromEvent`), HTTP Requests (using Angular's HTTP Client, Abstract Form Control events (`formControl.valueChanges`), timers (`interval`), and really an value can be created into an observable via the `of` operator.

That being said, I prefer using Angular's async pipe in the HTML template to react to event updates.  Async pipe creates a subscription in the HTML template so you don't have to subscribe in the Typescript file.  One benefit is that you remove the risk of introducing memory leaks from not unsubscribing to a subscription.  Some subscriptions like events from Angular's HTTP client unsubscribe (or complete) after the first event completes, but other subscriptions do not. If you subscribe to an observable that does not auto complete and you do not explicitly unsubscribe, every time the component is initialized, a new subscription will be created.  With async pipe, Angular automatically unsubscribes to the subscription when the component is destroyed.